# Deployd : Most secure, most elegant way to get all objects in a specific collection created by the logged-in user?

Tags: deployd

I think the title pretty much says it all... Brand new to Deployd, so any pointers about how best to go about this are appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

To get the objects in a collection created by the user (I assume you're using the javascript library dpd.js):

```
// Get the current user:
var currentUser;
dpd.users.me(function(result, error) {
    currentUser = result;
});

// query your collection with your currentUser id as parameter
dpd.yourcollection.get({creator:currentUser.id}, function(result) {
    // Do something with the result
    console.log(result);
});
```

Your collection should have a property "creator" that contains the id of the user who created the object (*).
Then, to secure your backend, go to the dashboard, in the ON_GET tab of your collection and secure it with this code:

```
 cancelUnless(isMe(this.creator), "You have to be the creator to view this item", 401);
```

More info about cancellUnless() and isMe() here:
http://docs.deployd.com/docs/collections/reference/event-api.md#s-cancelIf%28%29,%20cancelUnless%28%29-764

The good practice to secure your collections is to allow queries only if user is logged:

```
cancelUnless(me,"You have to be connected to view this item", 401);
```

Users collections should be particularly well secured (allow ON_PUT only by admin or something like that).

*: to automatically store the currentUserId in the creator property, you could also add this in the ON_POST event in the dashboard:

```
this.creator = me.id;
```

More info here: http://docs.deployd.com/docs/collections/reference/event-api.md#s-me-764

Answer (score 0):

As of version 0.8.9, event **ONBEFOREREQUEST** exists and you could just put this code in there:

```
cancelUnless(me);
query.creator = me.id;
```

This means that for every request sent to that endpoint, creator key would be queried to have the currently logged in user's id. If there's not currently logged in user, the request is canceled.